# Apache Rewrite : not matching pattern not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect visitors to my main domain when they perform requests on my subdomain followed by a not matching URI.

For example, a visitor can access a resource at `sub.domain.com/product/10` but he should be redirected to `domain.com` when he attempt to access other resources that not match `product/:id` on my subdomain like `sub.domain.com/anOtherResource`.

I have to do this with apache rewrite module. I found that `!` operator can do the job but it's not working for me.

Here is my Rewrite configuration from .htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L,R]
```

I also tested this configuration :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain\.com
RewriteRule !^/product/[0-9]+$ http://www.domain.com [L,R]
```

I don't know where is the mistake ...

[Edit]

The .htaccess file is configured for Wordpress. Here is the entire .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/[0-9]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the Wordpress Rewrite configuration so what's happened ?

### Step 1

I perform a request at sub.domain.com/product/1 so it **not match** these RewriteCond :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/[0-9]+$
```

Then, it **not** redirect to `www.domain.com`

### Step 2

It continue the rewriting to the next Cond (Worpdress rewriting):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

At this step, it send an **Internal Redirect** (not sent to the client) to `sub.domain.com/index.php`

### Step 3

Because of the redirection, it apply again the previous RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

It **match** the Cond, then it redirect the client to `www.domain.com` while I didn't expect it.

## The Solution

I fixed the problem by adding a RewriteCond on index.php as showing bellow :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/[0-9]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Now it manage the Internal Redirection sent by the Worpress Rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rules look ok, but try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub[.]domain[.]com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L,R]
```

If this doesn't work, then you might need to copy and paste the entire contents of your VirtualHost configuration since it could be something else causing a problem.

Comment: The first Cond works fine. When I remove the `!` in the second Cond then it applies the rule with /product/1. I suppose the problem is on the "not" expression. I edited my question with the full .htaccess content.

Comment: Since you are using .htaccess in a directory, the second cond should be: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^product/[0-9]+$